# Get substring of text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me get the substring of the following text.

I would like to be able to extract the text

```
PilotCube_2Year
```

FROM

```
/content/folder[@name=&apos;Reporting Packages&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;PiotCube_2Year&apos;]
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have tried `substring` and `Charindex` but could not really get the string `PilotCube_2Year`

Comment: You may want to look into `PATINDEX`

Comment: Is all of your data set up in the same format?

Comment: This looks like an XQuery path. What are you trying to do with that substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `package[@name=` is what tells you where the string you are looking for is, you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @toSearch  AS VARCHAR(100) = '/content/folder[@name=''Reporting Packages'']/package[@name=''PiotCube_2Year'']'
DECLARE @toFind AS VARCHAR(100)  = 'package[@name='
DECLARE @start AS INT = CHARINDEX(@toFind , @toSearch ) + LEN(@toFind) + 1

SELECT SUBSTRING(@toSearch,                              --expression
            @start,                                      --start
            CHARINDEX(']' , @toSearch, @start) - @start - 1) --length
```

**Result**

```
PiotCube_2Year
```